# library(tidyverse) gives error message never seen before

Tags: r, tidyverse

```r
library(tidyverse)
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
  namespace ‘tibble’ 2.1.3 is already loaded, but >= 3.0.0 is required
> In addition: Warning message:
> package ‘tidyverse’ was built under R version 3.6.3"
```

Tried a few things from the internet. No luck! Any help will be appreciated.

I am using the latest version of R studio, also updated all my packages recently.

Comment: Can you please update the packages `update.packages`

Comment: @akrun, I did update the packages. Didn't work.

Comment: Try: Quitting and Restarting R, update packages again and then load the tidy verse package.

Comment: @Dave2e, this worked!! Thanks a lot!